# Overwritten create method doesn't fire for relationship()->create()

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5.1

I want to add a new tag to a model by the following call:

```
Modul::find($id)->tags()->create($request->all());
```

The create method in the tag Modul is:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $attributes['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    return parent::create($attributes);
}
```

But it says that the user_id is not set.

When I call

```
Modul::find($id)->tags()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]));
```

everything works fine.

I made an echo call inside the create function but it's never called. So is there a secound create function I have to overwrite?

Comment: Would you check `dd(Auth::user()->id);` in the create function?

Comment: I did, but i just get the error that user_id is not set. when I write `$attributes['user_id'] = 1` it says that user_id is not set.

Comment: Is the `user_id` added to the `$fillable` array?

Comment: yeah it is. as I said: when i merge the the user_id with the request array everything works fine. But i want to add it inside the create function so i don't have to merge at every creation call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `create` method you're calling is not defined on the `Tag` model, it's defined on the relation class. So if you're relation is many-to-many, then the `create` method is the one defined on the [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L715-L727) class.

That method calls the `newInstance` model method internally. So if you want to add the `user_id` to the attributes, you can override that method or even the `__constructor`, as those methods create a new instance of the model. So this should work in your case:

```php
public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false)
{
    $attributes['user_id'] = Auth::id();

    return parent::newInstance($attributes, $exists);
}
```

That being said, it's better to pass the `user_id` as as a parameter, because otherwise you're tightly coupling the model to the authentication system, and it might have **unforeseen results** as the method is also used internally by Eloquent.